# help with simple SQL update + join

Tags: sql

I think this should be pretty simple, but I'm a SQL newb.

I have two tables. One is a list of items IDs and descriptions, the other is a map of corresponding old and new IDs. Like this:

```
    ID_MAP
OLD_ID   NEW_ID
---------------
1        101
2        102

    ITEMS
ID       DESCRIPTION
--------------------
1        "ItemA"
2        "ItemB"
...
101      <null>
102      <null>
```

I need to copy the old item descriptions to the new items according to the map. I think I need to use an `inner join` inside of an `update`, but it's not working and I'm not even sure that's the right way to go.

I'm trying statements like

```
update ITEMS
set (select ITEMS.DESCRIPTION
     from ITEMS
     join ID_MAP
     on ITEMS.ID = ID_MAP.NEW_ID) = 
    (select ITEMS.DESCRIPTION
     from ITEMS
     join ID_MAP
     on ITEMS.ID = ID_MAP.OLD_ID)
```

But of course it's not working. What should I be doing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
update new_item
    set description = old_item.description
    from items old_item
        inner join id_map im
            on old_item.id = im.old_id
        inner join items new_item
            on im.new_id = new_item.id
```

Answer (score 2):

Depending on if `UPDATE .. FROM` is available in your DBMS (SQL Server vs Oracle) one possibility is using correlated sub-queries for each of your column updates. Not as convenient if you are able to do `UPDATE FROM`.

```
UPDATE items i
SET i.id = (
  SELECT new_id
  FROM id_map
  WHERE old_id = i.id
)
, description = (
  SELECT description
  FROM id_map
  WHERE old_id = i.id
)
```

You could add the following to the end too

```
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM id_map
  WHERE old_id = id
)
```